# How to Insert HTML in a webpage using a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a Google Chrome extension where I can modify a particular webpage with custom features. As of now, to insert HTML, I'm doing this:

```
$('body').prepend('<div class="navbar"></div>');
$('body').append('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
```

The issue with this is that if my HTML code is very long, the code becomes really hard to read and manage.

Is there an easier method to do this?

Comment: Yep. Don't write code inside the extension. Use an IDE and copy/paste it in the extension when you want to test it.

Comment: Don't modify HTML directly, insert an iframe that points to your extension page whitelisted in web_accessible_resources. There are many examples.